# How to trace a token adress from an ERC 721 transfer transaction?

Tags: etherscan, events, erc-721, web3j, topics

I have an Ethereum node which I connect using web3j library. In the code I iterate over transactions of a particular block and try to fetch information about ERC721 transfers. In particular, I want to trace the token address.

For example, here is [a transaction transferring a token on Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5b4f46c6136b1236efddcab4284bb78c9ce29767197c32a98a5ec8d52af226ed).

Etherscan is able to reference the token address.

[image]

By checking topics in the logs of the transactions receipt, I was able to find the token id (which is a number 9984), but not [the token address](https://etherscan.io/token/0x123b30e25973fecd8354dd5f41cc45a3065ef88c).

**Question:** How to get a token address from an ERC721 transaction? How does Etherscan do it?

Comment: In the transaction receipt the contract address should appear with the logs entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this API endpoint for Ropsten Network. It will provide you all the details with tokenID and other details of your address.

https://api-ropsten.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokennfttx&address=<your_Contract_Address>&startblock=0&endblock=latest&sort=asc&apikey=<your_API_key>

I am using Ropsten API because my contract is deployed on Ropsten Testnet. You can adjust block with your starting block.